# MySQL returns 0 results when comparing datetime column

Tags: mysql

I have a datetime column named date_time in my table. When I try to get all entries for a date before a given date, I always get 0 results even though there are thousands in the DB.

For example, these are 3 rows from my table:

```
INSERT INTO `fixtures` (`id`, `opta_id`, `competition_id`, `season_id`, `status`, `round`, `date_time`, `timezone`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(825, 'g1011331', 8, 3, 1, 14, '2018-12-02 19:30:00', 'GMT', '2019-04-03 14:39:50', '2019-05-02 13:51:49'),
(890, 'g1011405', 8, 3, 1, 21, '2019-01-26 17:00:00', 'GMT', '2019-04-03 14:39:50', '2019-05-02 13:53:06'),
(891, 'g1011396', 8, 3, 1, 21, '2019-01-26 14:00:00', 'GMT', '2019-04-03 14:39:50', '2019-05-02 13:51:49');
```

And this query returns 0 results:

```
update fixtures set status=1 where date_time < '2019-04-30 00:00:00';
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the date type from your columns?

Comment: Your code works fine if the datatype of `date_time` is `datetime`. Or maybe it is not?

Comment: The data type is datetime, I've checked and re-checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `STR_TO_DATE` let `date_time` to datetime then compare.

```
update fixtures 
set status=1 
where STR_TO_DATE(date_time, '%Y-%m-%d %T') <  STR_TO_DATE('2019-04-30 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %T');
```